# Index running out of bound in for loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, for-loop, datatable

In my win forms application I have 2 listViews: listView1 and listView2.
listView1 has database tables which the user selects (one or more)
When a button is pressed listView2 shows all the columns pertaining to the table(s) selected.
When i select 2 tables from listView1, the nested loop runs out of bound even though it shows all columns for 1 table but since it runs out of bound, it does not get columns for the second table selected. Could you tell me where am i going wrong?
Here is my code:

```
conn.Open();
SqlCommand sc2 = new SqlCommand("select C_Name, T from (select CONCAT(Table_Schema,'.',Table_Name) T, Concat(Table_Name,'.',Column_Name) C_Name from  Information_Schema.columns) as Teo ;", conn);                
SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter(sc2);
sda2.Fill(dt);
conn.Close();
DataRow[] foundrows;
string express;                
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
{                 
    MessageBox.Show(listView1.CheckedItems.Count.ToString());
    express="T ='" + listView1.CheckedItems[i].Text+"'";
    foundrows = dt.Select(express);
    MessageBox.Show(foundrows.Length.ToString());

    for (int p = 0; p < foundrows.Length; i++)
    {                        
        listView2.Items.Add(foundrows[i][1].ToString());                        
    }                        
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error code and which line is throwing it?

Comment: Do you mean to be incrementing the i index in the second loop? for (int p = 0; p < foundrows.Length; i++)

Comment: @Ehz got it. Your second loop uses `i` when it should be using `p`.

Comment: Error: "index was outside the bounds of the array"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change both what is incremented and what you use for the index in your second loop:

```
foundrows = dt.Select(express);
MessageBox.Show(foundrows.Length.ToString());

for (int p = 0; p < foundrows.Length; p++)
{                        
     listView2.Items.Add(foundrows[p][1].ToString());                        
}
```

The i++ in the second loop will cause your index to increment outside of the limit of i < listView1.CheckedItems.Count

Using i for your index in the second loop will cause an out of bounds exception when foundrows.Length !=   listView1.CheckedItems.Count, and is probably not what you intended anyway

Comment: Why the **p** instead of p? Is that just to highlight it better?

Comment: Sorry that was just markdown to bold the variable, which I don't think I formatted correctly in code view. I have removed it

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int p = 0; p < foundrows.Length; i++)
{                        
    listView2.Items.Add(foundrows[i][1].ToString());                        
}
```

should be

```
for (int p = 0; p < foundrows.Length; p++)
{                        
    listView2.Items.Add(foundrows[p][1].ToString());                        
}
```

Comment: It should also be `p++`.

Answer (score 1):

It is running out of bounds because you have:

```
for (int p = 0; p < foundrows.Length; i++)
{                        
    listView2.Items.Add(foundrows[i][1].ToString());                        
}
```

And it should be:

```
for (int p = 0; p < foundrows.Length; p++)
{                        
    listView2.Items.Add(foundrows[p][1].ToString());                        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, the second table has two columns?

Because, you are doing `listView2.Items.Add(foundrows[i][1].ToString());`

`foundrows[rowindex][cellindex]` is it available in the second table?

Comment: Please don't post a comment as an answer.

Comment: Yes, the sqlcommand shows two columns that were added to the datatable

Comment: @Abion47 you got it, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be "p" instead of "i" in the second loop?

```
for (int p = 0; p < foundrows.Length; p++)
     {                        
         listView2.Items.Add(foundrows[p][1].ToString());                        
     }
```

Comment: It should also be `p++`.